# select query between date in Android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

[image: Table]

Above is My data screenshot. I need to select catalog if it ranges between the from date and to date. My query is "`select catalog from hhItemDiscountOne where fromDate >= '20190305' and toDate <= '20190305'`". But i didn't get values even though the date is between the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mistake I often make on first sight. You are mixing the from and to conditions.

There is no entry with a fromDate >= '20190305', they are both '20190301' which is smaller. So if you are searching values where the date is in the range, your condition needs to be

```
fromDate <= '20190305' and toDate >= '20190305'
```

The `<=` and `>=` are turned